# How do I add a Linux VM to an Azure DevOps Environment in Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I am trying to register a Linux Ubuntu VM created as part of a Terraform script to an existing Azure DevOps Environment called "Production". To do this I am trying to use the script offered by Azure DevOps as part of a `custom_data` entry:

```
locals {
  custom_data = <<CUSTOM_DATA
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update

mkdir azagent;cd azagent;curl -fkSL -o vstsagent.tar.gz https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/3.220.0/vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.0.tar.gz;tar -zxvf vstsagent.tar.gz; if [ -x "$(command -v systemctl)" ]; then ./config.sh --unattended --environment --environmentname "Production" --acceptteeeula --agent $HOSTNAME --url https://dev.azure.com/my-dev-ops/ --work _work --projectname 'My Project' --auth PAT --token <snip> --runasservice; sudo ./svc.sh install; sudo ./svc.sh start; else ./config.sh --environment --environmentname "Production" --acceptteeeula --agent $HOSTNAME --url https://dev.azure.com/my-dev-ops/ --work _work --projectname 'My Project' --auth PAT --token <snip>; ./run.sh; fi

sudo apt install docker.io -y 

sudo apt install azure-cli -y


  CUSTOM_DATA
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "primary_vm" {
  name                            = "vmname"
  location                        = "uksouth"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  size                            = "Standard_B1s"
  admin_username                  = "user"
  admin_password                  = "pass"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.id]
  custom_data                     = base64encode(local.custom_data)
  
  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = null
  }

  os_disk {
    name                 = "vmname"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"
    sku       = "20_04-lts-gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Note that there is more to the file but they should be the relevant sections.

The result is a VM that gets created with docker and the azure-cli installed but the VM is not registered to the environment. The VM doesn't even contain a folder called `azagent`.

If I take the azagent command and run it on the VM myself in an SSH session it works in unattended mode as expected with no errors.

Is there something wrong with the approach? I haven not been able to find any useful feedback from the command in boot diagnostics or other logs.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution was to use the `remote_exec` provisioner instead of the `custom_data` approach.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "primary_vm" {
//
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "The script"
    ]

    connection {
     //SSH Connection Details
    }
  }
}
```